# Inserting array data to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Basically i wanted this on my table,

```
--------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   related_products_ids |
| ------------------------------------------
|    1            |   2                    |
| ------------------------------------------
|    1            |   3                    |
| ------------------------------------------
|    1            |   4                    |
--------------------------------------------
```

I have checkboxes,

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category1"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 1
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category2"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 2
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 3
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 4
```

What i wanted is to insert checked checkboxes into the table by `products_id`.

I use this php code,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['rp_product']); $i++)
 {
  $check_val1 .= $_POST['rp_product'][$i] .",";
 }
$check_val = trim($check_val1, ','); 
unset($check_val1);

$insert_rp_ids1 = explode(',', $check_val);

 for($i=0;$i<count($insert_rp_ids1);$i++) {
   $usetag = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(ltrim(rtrim($insert_rp_ids1[$i]))));
      if($usetag == "") continue;
        $array1 = array('products_id' => (int)$products_id,
                     'related_products_ids' => $usetag);
        $wpdb->insert(TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS, $array1);
      }
 }
```

The problem is that, only the first checked checkbox is only inserted. What seems to be the problem or do you have other solution? Please help.

Comment: Sidenotes: 1)ltrim+rtrim = trim. 2)why you implode then explode the array, and not just loop over it directly? 3)can avoid using "continue" and just use if != ""; 4) you can insert multiple values without querying in loop

Comment: @DamienPirsy How to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trim will remove all commas',' in the string and you are exploding with ',' how will it return anything????? $_POST['rp_product'] will directly return an array. You can use simply use foreach to browse the array and insert.

Comment: $ids=$_POST['rp_product'];    foeach($ids as $id){ insert into Table $id}. This is the general code. if you want specific code, I can give you.

Comment: I have found the problem.. its on the database primary key.. Thank you.